# Is there a function with the following properties?

Tags: limits, functions

I am looking for a function $f(x,k)$ with the following properties:

$$ f(0,k)=1$$
$$ f(1,k)=0$$
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}f(x,k)= \Bigg \{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text {if} & x=0\\
0 & \text {if} & x>0
\end{matrix}$$

For my project, I am currently using the function:

$$g(x,k) = 1-\tanh(k \cdot x)$$

which lacks the property $g(1,k) = 0$ (unless $k$ tends to infinity).

Is there such a function?

Comment: Do you require your function to be continuous?

Comment: A problem with $f(x,k):=(1-x)\exp(-k\,x)$ ?

Comment: A slight modification to $(1-x) \exp(-|kx|)$ ensures the desired properties for all $x, k \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you all very much.
@RaymondManzoni Can you write your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution could be $\;\displaystyle f(x,k):=(1-x)\exp(-k\,x)\;$ for nonnegative values of $k$ and $x$ (or use absolute value in the more general case as suggested by heropup).
Many other solutions are possible like $\;\displaystyle f(x,k):=\frac {1-x^2}{1+x^2}\exp(-k\,x)\;$ and so on...